# how to enable a disabled image submit button using checkbox?

Tags: jquery, html

Here are the two code snippets that are part of my form

//checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" style="margin-right:3px">I confirm that the details on this form are correct.
```

//submit button

```
<input type="image" src="images/submit-btn.png" border="0" >
```

now my question is, how to enable disable the submit button using the checkbox , via jquery ?

Comment: from what i can see your submit button is not actually doing anything, i assume you assign a click handler on the anchor tag ?

Comment: Here is demo check [it](http://jsfiddle.net/KK2aV/19/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
$(':checkbox').change(function(){
    $('input[type="image"]').attr("disabled", !$(this).attr('checked'));
});

$('input[type="image"]').click(function(){
alert("123");
});
```

**EDIT:**

```
<input type="image" src="images/submit-btn.png" border="0" disabled="disabled"/>
```

**fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/hKAE5/**

Comment: hi, i changed it to this <input type="image" src="images/submit-btn.png" border="0" >, so how's that ?

Comment: what if let's say, the submit button is disabled by default, and the ticking of checkbox should enabled it.. kindly update your answer, thanks

Comment: add disabled="disabled" in image tag.. updated the answer.. check the fiddle example also.

Answer (score 1):

You have probably put wrong question.
Above submit button actually is not image submit button.

Image submit button is

```
<INPUT TYPE="image" SRC="images/submit-btn.png" id="submit_id" />
```

If you want run code when checkbox (with ID checkbox_id) is checked use following snippet:

```
$('#checkbox_id').change(function() { 
if ($(this).is(':checked'))
    $("#submit_id").attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

**EDIT:**
If you want submit button disabled by default you need:

```
<INPUT TYPE="image" SRC="images/submit-btn.png" id="submit_id" disabled="disabled" />
```

And then you just change above snippet, so when user click on checkbox, button will be enabled:

```
     $('#checkbox_id').change(function() { 
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            // DISABLE
            $("#submit_id").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        } else {
            // ENABLE            
            $("#submit_id").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
     });
```

Comment: i updated my question... how to make the button disabled by default, and, by using jquery, how to enable it by ticking the checkbox?..please update your answer, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that works with your existing markup.  You can test here: http://jsfiddle.net/brentmn/yPmSV/

html:

```
<input type="checkbox" style="margin-right:3px">I confirm that the details on this form are correct.

<a class="submit disabled" href="#"><img src="images/submit-btn.png" border="0" ></a>
```

js:

```
$(function() {
    var $check = $(':checkbox');
    var $submit = $('.submit');

    $submit.on('.click', function() {
        return $check.is(':checked');
    });

    $check.on('click', configureSubmit);

    function configureSubmit() {
        if ($check.is(':checked')) {
            $submit.removeClass('disabled');
        } else {
            $submit.addClass('disabled');
        }
    }

    configureSubmit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your submit button is a link (not a real submit button) I assume you're using javascript to handle a click event on the link. If you want to disable the submit you should either provide the way you handle a click on this link, or you should use a submit button instead. 
When using a submit button you can set the disabled attribute to disable it.